# WPP vertical scrollViewer is not apprearing

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I have a wpf user control which has Grid with row definitions as Auto. and controls defined in that in grid. Outside of this this i have scroll viewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility as set to Auto.

```
 <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" />
        <telerik:RadRichTextBox Name="Name" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="2" 
                                Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AcceptsReturn="True"
                                Height="500" Width="750" DocumentInheritsDefaultStyleSettings="True" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="13">
            <telerik:RadRichTextBox.Document>
                <telerik:RadDocument LineSpacingType="AtLeast" LineSpacing="0" 
                                     ParagraphDefaultSpacingAfter="0" ParagraphDefaultSpacingBefore="0">

                </telerik:RadDocument>
            </telerik:RadRichTextBox.Document>
        </telerik:RadRichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am loading the above control as content of Rad tab item from another view.

I could not able to view vertical scroll bar when i resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

......
<telerik:RadRichTextBox Grid.Row="1" ...... 
 />
```